# After ceph volumes are removed , it didn't reflect the removed size

Tags: storage

I found same problem in other case.

http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2013-September/033843.html?fbclid=IwAR0yLcTERbXV4cEPdJveqABz-ULUO71jz3M96OjzOzsYRmWJtlYrwW_ig-E

It's same issue.and found there has been no solution yet..

===========================================================

env: ceph jewel (ceph version: 10.2.7) used rbd format
     openstack ocata  version

problem : we removed the openstack volume, but didn’t reflect it. 
How can we reflect the empty rooms?

We used ceph  and found issue when we delete Openstack volumes.
Steps for reproduce:

1. Detach and deleting Openstack volumes from instance.
2. we hope to get the 120TB free size , but it didn’t reflect by checking ceph df command
3. Checking Ceph size (ceph -s & cepch df)
4. The capacity of the "rdb du -p volumes" command and "rados df -p volumes" are significantly different.

we checked all site ( 4 site in same env), and there are no different during rbd/rados command)
Only this site made the problem.

```
[root@sm03 ~]# ceph --version
ceph version 10.2.7 (50e863e0f4bc8f4b9e31156de690d765af245185)
 
<Delete Openstack volumes>
we delete about 120TB by below command
openstack volume delete  a3ca9ef-4ea0-4f84-9b71-f48dd800fc81
…
…
<After delete volumes>
[root@sm01 ~]# ceph -s
    cluster b37f1747-017e-4d99-ab6e-9bc2b470a04a
     health HEALTH_OK
     monmap e1: 3 mons at {sm01=192.168.1.54:6789/0,sm02=192.168.1.55:6789/0,sm03=192.168.1.56:6789/0}
            election epoch 66, quorum 0,1,2 sm01,sm02,sm03
     osdmap e24319: 160 osds: 160 up, 160 in
            flags sortbitwise,require_jewel_osds
      pgmap v57198458: 10048 pgs, 7 pools, 198 TB data, 50515 kobjects
            395 TB used, 186 TB / 581 TB avail
               10043 active+clean
                   5 active+clean+scrubbing+deep
  client io 24151 kB/s rd, 38743 kB/s wr, 1315 op/s rd, 1901 op/s wr

[root@sm02 centos]# ceph df
GLOBAL:
    SIZE     AVAIL     RAW USED     %RAW USED
    581T      186T         395T         68.01
POOLS:
    NAME         ID     USED      %USED     MAX AVAIL     OBJECTS
    rbd          0      1193G      2.37        49187G       305659
    images       1      3040G      5.82        49187G       389282
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    volumes      2       194T     72.93        73781G     51037021
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    vms          3          0         0        49187G            2
    backups      4          0         0        49187G            0
    osc-test     8          0         0        49187G            2
    volumes2     9          0         0        49187G            0
```

Ceph is configured two copy that i thought can make 120TB in minimal but i got still 3TB after 3days from deleting

```
[root@sm03 osc]# rados df  -p volumes (used about 194 TB)
pool name                 KB      objects       clones     degraded      unfound           rd        rd KB           wr        wr KB
volumes         208456711224     51035676       697840            0            0  77223140580 692432070927  23760624643 303477785046

[root@sm03 ~]# rbd du -p volumes (used about 87TB)
NAME                                                                                      PROVISIONED    USED
volume-01afa884-750c-4310-a46c-139ae6edf62f                                                     1000G   4096k
...
volume-fcd81520-546a-475c-95b0-9a2753fb3f2a                                                     3072G   3059G
volume-fee20996-e0d5-4559-a672-002248f9f795                                                   102400M  90484M
<TOTAL>                                                                                          129T  87145G

and we chagned the debug mode to 2/5
but there were not no clues
==============
[root@s01 ceph]# tail -n 10  ceph-osd.2.log
2019-07-30 20:04:30.670318 7f8ec8390700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : 2.df scrub ok
2019-07-30 20:04:36.451665 7f8ecab95700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : 2.896 scrub starts
2019-07-30 20:04:40.082636 7f8ec8390700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : 2.896 scrub ok
2019-07-30 20:04:43.452028 7f8ec9b93700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : 2.1234 scrub starts
2019-07-30 20:04:47.321024 7f8ec9b93700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : 2.1234 scrub ok
2019-07-30 20:04:51.452846 7f8ec7b8f700  0 log_channel(cluster) log [INF] : 2.1981 deep-scrub starts
2019-07-30 20:04:54.625680 7f8e8a7fe700  1 leveldb: Level-0 table #979119: started
2019-07-30 20:04:54.645016 7f8e8a7fe700  1 leveldb: Level-0 table #979119: 1323944 bytes OK
2019-07-30 20:04:54.646277 7f8e8a7fe700  1 leveldb: Delete type=0 #979117
------------------
```

===================================================
we checked another site..but there are a little difference

```
[root@ceph-mon01 ~]# rados df -p volumes (used 51TB)
POOL_NAME USED   OBJECTS  CLONES COPIES   MISSING_ON_PRIMARY UNFOUND DEGRADED RD_OPS      RD   WR_OPS     WR   
volumes   51769G 13268662  96335 39805986                  0       0        0 54945485259 448T 4333085196 455T 

total_objects    14663308
total_used       162T
total_avail      135T
total_space      298T



[root@ceph-mon01 ~]# rbd du -p volumes  (used 52TB)
NAME                                                                                      PROVISIONED    USED 
rbdtest                                                                                         1024G    200G 
...
<TOTAL>
```